# Trying to catch the oncreate of a form

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

The project I work on consists of several 100 of forms.
They are mostly called from the mainform. The application name is in all of the formcaptions.

Now a different "version" of the application has to have the form captions changed to another applicationname. But this is conditional.

What I came up with was binding the

```
Screen.OnActiveFormChange := ScreenOnActiveFormChange;
```

in the formcreate and making a procedure for that.

```
procedure TFormMAIN.ScreenOnActiveFormChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if Newversion then begin
    if assigned(screen.activeform) then begin
      Screen.ActiveForm.Caption := SwapFormCaption(Screen.ActiveForm.Caption);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

This works well in 95% of the cases. But in those 5% the form is shown too fast. The window is drawn before the caption is updated and windows leaves it there. But the caption already has a new value.
What worked remedy was increasing and decreasing the form height by 1 pixel and then it would show right. form.repaint didn't help here.
This is a rather ugly way of doing things.

What I really want is to intercept the creation of the sub-form instead of the activation. I have tried to find resources about that but wasn't successful.

Comment: The best way to do this is to make all your forms derive from a common base class. Then you can control settings common to all forms from a single location

Comment: After further investigation I think it is somehow a videobuffer bug. When I drag the window, the caption doesn't change and stays wrong. Unless I drag it to slip off the desktop. When I drag it back, the part that wasn't shown on the dekstop is changed to the correct caption while the part that remained visible stays wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using window api ?

```
SetWindowText(Screen.ActiveForm.Handle,PChar(SwapFormCaption(Screen.ActiveForm.Caption));
```

Edit :
1 more suggestion : Add a DrawMenuBar API call to force redraw of the window menu bar

```
DrawMenuBar(Screen.ActiveForm.Handle);
```

Comment: This does exactly the same as the code I posted, with the same problem.